# Break down JSON string in simple perl or simple unix?

Tags: objective-c, c, json, perl, unix

ok so i have have this

```
{"status":0,"id":"7aceb216d02ecdca7ceffadcadea8950-1","hypotheses":[{"utterance":"hello how are you","confidence":0.96311796}]}
```

and at the moment i'm using this shell command to decode it to get the string i need,

```
echo $x | grep -Po '"utterance":.*?[^\\]"' | sed -e s/://g -e s/utterance//g -e 's/"//g'
```

but this only works when you have a grep compiled with perl and plus the script i use to get that JSON string is written in perl, so is there any way i can do this same decoding in a simple perl script or a simpler unix command, or better yet, c or objective-c?

the script i'm using to get the json is here, http://pastebin.com/jBGzJbMk and if you want a file to use then download http://trevorrudolph.com/a.flac

Comment: What *is* the string you need? Post the output you want, not the command you use to get the output.

Comment: oh! sorry, i just wat from that, "hello how are you"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
perl -MJSON -nE 'say decode_json($_)->{hypotheses}[0]{utterance}'
```

in script form:

```
use JSON;
while (<>) {
   print decode_json($_)->{hypotheses}[0]{utterance}, "\n"
}
```

Comment: `echo {"status":0,"id":"7aceb216d02ecdca7ceffadcadea8950-1","hypotheses":[{"utterance":"hello how are you","confidence":0.96311796}]} | perl -MJSON -pe 'decode_json($_)->{hypotheses}[0]{utterance}'`

Comment: `malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "status:0 id:7aceb216...") at -e line 1, <> line 1.
`

Comment: id love it in a regular script form, im running a .pl script to get that string to pring so decode before print could be good

Comment: @Trevor Rudolph, You didn't properly quote your JSON.

Comment: I'd add `-000` to handle multi-line JSON. Also, outputing the 1st element of an array sure looks fishy.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I'm not sure if I can deduce what you are after correctly, but this is a way to decode that JSON string in perl.

Of course, you'll need to know the data structure in order to get the data you need. The line that prints the "utterance" string is commented out in the code below.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;

my $json = decode_json 
q#{"status":0,"id":"7aceb216d02ecdca7ceffadcadea8950-1","hypotheses":[{"utterance":"hello how are you","confidence":0.96311796}]}#;
#print $json->{'hypotheses'}[0]{'utterance'};
print Dumper $json;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'status' => 0,
          'hypotheses' => [
                            {
                              'utterance' => 'hello how are you',
                              'confidence' => '0.96311796'
                            }
                          ],
          'id' => '7aceb216d02ecdca7ceffadcadea8950-1'
        };
```

**Quick hack:**

```
while (<>) {
    say for /"utterance":"?(.*?)(?<!\\)"/;
}
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
perl -lnwe 'print for /"utterance":"(.+?)(?<!\\)"/g' inputfile.txt
```

The one-liner is troublesome if you happen to be using Windows, since `"` is interpreted by the shell.

**Quick hack#2:**

This will hopefully go through any hash structure and find keys.

```
my $json = decode_json $str;
say find_key($json, 'utterance');

sub find_key {
    my ($ref, $find) = @_;
    if (ref $ref) {
        if (ref $ref eq 'HASH' and defined $ref->{$find}) {
            return $ref->{$find};
        } else {
            for (values $ref) {
                my $found = find_key($_, $find);
                if (defined $found) {
                    return $found;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: but i want it to be simple enough so i don't need to get JSON from CPAN and is utterance a variable? or a reference?

Comment: @TrevorRudolph In the `$json` variable above, it is a hash key. Not quite sure what you are asking there. The problem with trying to parse this with a regex is escaped quotes. A string such as `"hello my name is \"Bob\"."` will require you to jump through some hoops to properly parse.

Comment: yea but can i do from what you got, `print Dumper $json->'utterance';`

Comment: @TrevorRudolph You mean to print any key in the structure with the name "utterance"? I suppose it might be possible.

Comment: yea, print the string of the json key 'utterance'

Comment: @TrevorRudolph To print the value, simply remove the `#` in the code above. To print *any* value in the `$json` hash, you'd need some kind of recursive search through the hash.

Comment: sounds confusing, but im just looking to gett the utterance string so, this would be helpful if i was just asking for phasing help

Comment: @TrevorRudolph I added a quick hack to simply extract the values with a regex. I would use it with caution, though.

Comment: @TrevorRudolph I also added a search subroutine that will (hopefully) extract keys matching a certain word.

Comment: oh, and 1 more thing, when i do it with a different input source than an echo, i get this error,

Comment: `Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/"utterance":"(.+?)( <-- HERE ?<!\)"/ at -e line 1.
`

Comment: @TrevorRudolph The input won't affect the regex. That looks like you forgot to escape the backslash, which will instead escape the closing parenthesis. `(?<!\\)` not `(?<!\)`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the naming, it's possible to have multiple hypotheses. The prints the utterance of each hypothesis:

```
echo '{"status":0,"id":"7aceb216d02ecdca7ceffadcadea8950-1","hypotheses":[{"utterance":"hello how are you","confidence":0.96311796}]}' | \
   perl -MJSON::XS -n000E'
      say $_->{utterance}
         for @{ JSON::XS->new->decode($_)->{hypotheses} }'
```

Or as a script:

```
use feature qw( say );
use JSON::XS;
my $json = '{"status":0,"id":"7aceb216d02ecdca7ceffadcadea8950-1","hypotheses":[{"utterance":"hello how are you","confidence":0.96311796}]}';
say $_->{utterance}
   for @{ JSON::XS->new->decode($json)->{hypotheses} };
```

Comment: `malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "status:0 id:7aceb216...") at -e line 2, <> chunk 1.`

Comment: Changed to look like a script, as requested.

Comment: @Trevor Rudolph, What is that? Are you saying you have invalid JSON? It works fine with the JOSN your provided in the OP.

Comment: @Trevor Rudolph, Oh I see, you *removed* the quotes I have in my code. Don't do that.

Comment: no, i still get malformed error with quotes around json string

Comment: @Trevor Rudolph, Then tell us what command you ran. The one in my post works fine. I can't help you debug code you haven't shown.

Comment: @Trevor Rudolph, There was a problem with the script version, though. Fixed.

Comment: haha, it outputs the right thing but on a new line it still gets the error, it outputs the string, and the error :P

Comment: oh, and the first cod box returns ok, its just that when i run it as a pl script i get the correct out put with an error

Comment: @Trevor Rudolph, What error? I've run this code. It produces no error. It's basically the same code that Eric Strom posted after me, and you said that produces no error. (Mine handles newlines and multiple hypotheses correctly, where his doesn't, though.)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any modules from CPAN and try a regex instead there are multiple variants you can try:

```
# JSON is on a single line:
$json = '{"other":"stuff","hypo":[{"utterance":"hi, this is \"bob\"","moo":0}]}';
# RegEx with negative look behind:
# Match everything up to a double quote without a Backslash in front of it
print "$1\n" if ($json =~ m/"utterance":"(.*?)(?<!\\)"/)
```

This regex works if there is only one utterance. It doesn't matter what else is in the string around it, since it only searches for the double quoted string following the utterance key.

For a more robust version you could add whitespace where necessary/possible and make the `.` in the RegEx match newlines: `m/"utterance"\s*:\s*"(.*?)(?<!\\)"/s`

If you have multiple entries for the utterance confidence hash/object, changing case and  weird formatting of the JSON string try this:

```
# weird JSON:
$json = <<'EOJSON';
{
    "status":0,
    "id":"an ID",
    "hypotheses":[
        {
            "UtTeraNcE":"hello my name is \"Bob\".",
            "confidence":0.0
        },
        {
            'utterance' : 'how are you?',
            "confidence":0.1
        },
        {
            "utterance"
                : "
                thought
                so!
                ",
            "confidence" : 0.9
        }
    ]
}
EOJSON
# RegEx with alternatives:
print "$1\n" while ( $json =~ m/["']utterance["']\s*:\s*["'](([^\\"']|\\.)*)["']/gis);
```

The main part of this RegEx is `"(([^\\"]|\\.)*)"`. Description in detail as extended regex:

```
/
["']    # opening quotes
(       # start capturing parentheses for $1
(       # start of grouping alternatives
[^\\"'] # anything that's not a backslash or a quote
|       # or
\\.     # a backslash followed by anything
)       # end of grouping
*       # in any quantity
)       # end capturing parentheses
["']    # closing quotes
/xgs
```

If you have many data sets and speed is a concern you can add the o modifier to the regex and use character classes instead of the i modifier. You can suppress the capturing of the alternatives to $2 with clustering parenthesis `(?:pattern)`. Then you get this final result:

```
m/["'][uU][tT][tT][eE][rR][aA][nN][cC][eE]["']\s*:\s*["']((?:[^\\"']|\\.)*)["']/gos
```

Yes, sometimes perl looks like a big explosion in a bracket factory ;-)

Comment: i see what your doing, it works fantasticly if i just said `$json = '{"status":0,"id":"7aceb216d02ecdca7ceffadcadea8950-1","hypotheses":[{"utterance":"hello how are you","confidence":0.96311796}]}'` but im using a script to get the json, let me post the script and a link to a test file

Comment: ok, so the filter isnt working when i try to put $response as the variavle

Comment: Why use a bunch of `[uU][tT]...` when you can just add the `/i` modifier to the regex?

Comment: @TLP An O'Reilly Book I read some time ago claimed that character classes were faster than the i modifier for case insensitive matching. So it's just a minor speed improvement, but I haven't checked if that's still valid with newer versions of perl..

Comment: @Trevor It's not working because $response is not a string, but a HTTP::Response object. Modify your test script like this and it should work: `if ( $response->is_success ) { print "$1\n" if ($response->content =~ m/["']utterance["']\s*:\s*["']((?:[^\\"']|\\.)*)["']/ios); }`

Comment: so is regex faster than json_decode and doesnt use a library?

Comment: That depends :) Since regexes are a builtin and don't require a module compile time is always faster and since there are fewer function calls internally in perl runtime should also be faster than with the JSON module. The JSON module actually has two implementations for the parsing and conversion: JSON::PP wich comes with the JSON module (it's pure perl code and slow) and JSON::XS wich is written in C but must be installed seperately - See [link](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-2.32/XS.pm#SPEED) for a comparision.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm working and talking at the phone and writing here at the same time.

Comment: @ChrisH Doing some benchmarking, I can't detect any notable speed difference between using `/i` modifier and character classes for a matching regex (2-4% difference in favour of `/i` modifier). However, for a non-matching regex, the `/i` modifier is 76% faster.

Comment: @TLP So it's pretty much irrelavant now. Good to know and thanks for testing.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out for unix but would love to see your perl and c, objective-c answers...

```
echo $X | sed -e 's/.*utterance//' -e 's/confidence.*//' -e s/://g -e 's/"//g' -e 's/,//g'
```

:D

shorter copy of the same sed:

```
echo $X | sed -e 's/.*utterance//;s/confidence.*//;s/://g;s/"//g;s/,//g'
```

Comment: For objective-C there are various libraries, including one provided by Apple in iOS 5. For Perl there is this: http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.53/lib/JSON.pm . Or are you only interested in answers that avoid using libraries?

Comment: im ok if its in c or objective-c source so i can compile it all into 1 utility

Answer (score 0):

Just stubmled upon another nice method of doing this, i finaly found how to acsess the Mac OS X JavaScript engine form commandline, heres the script,

```
alias jsc='/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/jsc'
x='{"status":0,"id":"7aceb216d02ecdca7ceffadcadea8950-1","hypotheses":[{"utterance":"hello how are you","confidence":0.96311796}]}'
jsc -e "print(${x}['hypotheses'][0]['utterance'])"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, yes i came up with another answer, im strudying python and it reads arrays in both its python format and the same format as a json so, i jsut made this one liner when your variable is x

```
python -c "print ${x}['hypotheses'][0]['utterance']"
```